# Priority event-based Dispatcher with a TypedActor

Tags: java, actor, akka

Is it possible (or even advisable) to use a PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher with a TypedActor, in either Akka 1.3 or 2.0?  I'm hoping to set higher priorities for specific message types, which correspond 1-to-1 with the methods exposed in the TypedActor interfaces.

For example, if there were methods a(), b() and c(), I'd like calls to c() to have a higher priority than the a() or b() calls...

In [the 1.3 documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/java/dispatchers.html) I see how to use either a PriorityGenerator or even a Comparator to specify the priorities by the Message class type, for example.  But I'm not sure how that ties in with the messages being generated for the TypedActor method calls.

Is there anything I'm missing in the 2.0 documentation which would make this easier than in 1.3?  Or is this something which is just simply more difficult because I'm using a TypedActor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, is possible, just create your [dispatcher configurator](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/java/dispatchers.html#Mailbox_configuration_examples), specify the dispatcher id in your [TypedProps](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/java/typed-actors.html#Creating_Typed_Actors) prioritize the right [MethodCall](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/#akka.actor.TypedActor%24%24MethodCall)(s)

Comment: Thanks again, Viktor!  I really appreciate all of your feedback.